# 'cp932' codec can't encode character '\u98c8' in position 32: illegal multibyte sequence

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, web-scraping, encode

I want to write strings to a file but get a UnicodeEncodeError.

```
      7 with open('testfile.txt', 'w') as f:
      8     for item in list:
----> 9         f.write("%s\n" % item)
```

**UnicodeEncodeError**: 'cp932' codec can't encode character '\u98c8' in position 32: illegal multibyte sequence

How to fix this?

My program gets a text from web pages and saves them as a .txt file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting utf-8 encoding to your file data,

```
with open('testfile.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for item in list:
        f.write("%s\n" % item)
```